# Jenkins POD restarts how to persists Jenkins configuration and plugin

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I have deployed my Jenkins as part of kubernetes yaml file and also enabled Persist volume claim, when my Jenkins pod is restarts, i lost my all the jobs and configuration which means i need to re-install all Jenkins suggest plugin, configure kubernetes cloud, configure git repo, and create new pipeline job.

cloud you please help me how to avoid above scenario.

vi jenkins-deployment.yaml

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-master
  namespace: jenkins
  labels:
    app: jenkins-master
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins-master
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins-master
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        - containerPort: 50000
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /login
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 300
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 2
          failureThreshold: 5
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/var"
          name: jenkins-home
          subPath: jenkins_home
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 800m
            memory: 3Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 3Gi
      volumes:
      - name: jenkins-home
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pvc-jenkins-home
```

vi jenkins-pvc.yaml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pvc-jenkins-home
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  storageClassName: efs
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Mi
```

```
 kubectl get pvc -n jenkins
NAME               STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
pvc-jenkins-home   Bound    pvc-4ccf3f55-6894-4fee-88d7-58dd7584b837   10Mi       RWO            efs            59m
```

Please let me know if any details required from my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove the `subpath`from `volumeMounts` as subPath will overwrite everything under the `/var` directory. so it should be just like this

```
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /var
  name: jenkins-home
```